# C++ OpenCV Color Thersholding HSV images Errors

Tags: c++, opencv, hsv

So basically Im trying to detect a green target using Canny edge detection and color threshold. The original image as shown below is an example of what im trying to detect.

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

After applying canny edge detection this is what appears.

CannyEdge Image:

[image: CannyEdge Image]

From here I want only the green rectangle targets to appear so I use the  inRange function and input the ranges of HSV I got from GIMP of that certain green target in that picture. However I divded the Hue value by 2 as I heard that OpenCV uses Hue values 0 - 180 unlike GIMP which uses 0 - 360 and still end up with a black output image from the inRange function....

**How do you only make the green rectangles appear?**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;

Mat ORIGINAL_img;
Mat HSV_img, FINAL_img, MASKED_img, BLURRED_img;

Mat dst, detectededges;





int main() {


    ORIGINAL_img = imread("straight7.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);


    cvtColor(ORIGINAL_img, HSV_img, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    inRange(HSV_img, Scalar(80, 150, 15), Scalar(100, 255, 60), MASKED_img);
    blur(MASKED_img, BLURRED_img, Size(3,3));
    Canny(BLURRED_img, detectededges, 50, 20, 3);
    dst = Scalar::all(0);
    HSV_img.copyTo(dst, detectededges);


    imwrite("cannyoutput.jpg", dst);
    imwrite("colormaskoutput.jpg", MASKED_img);


    //imshow("color", HSV_img);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `inRange` should be working on your HSV image, not your edge image.

Comment: Is there no way to use it on he edge image? Or is there anyway to isolate certain edges by color?

Comment: First do the color segmentation and then do the edges.

Comment: Your edge image is a binary image, it's just black and white. You're trying to filter the colors, obviously you cannot filter the black and white image to find a certain color. Instead isolate the color by applying `inRange()` to your HSV image, which will give you a black and white image which you can then find the edges of.

Comment: So I tried what you guys suggested by applying inRange to the HSV image and I made the lower bound (0, 0, 0) and the upper bound (180, 255, 255), and it still appeared black... shouldnt it not mask out anything cause I allowed all colors to be visible? Here is image to code https://imgur.com/a/uvcYb

Comment: Please always copy and paste code. All you have to do is add an extra indent into your text editor and then copy/paste it here to get it to display as code. If someone were to reply by editing your code, they'd have to type it all manually. Anyways I think your problem is setting those three `Mat` equal to `image.clone()`. This isn't going to clone it three times, it's going to create multiple references to a single clone. Also you want a single channel, and not three channel, image for your mask. You don't even need to initialize it. Just create a `Mat mask` and pass it in to `inRange`.

Comment: Sorry about that this is my first time asking a question in stackoverflow. Anyway I updated the code to what I currently have in my editor, which delivers the result I want. However as you can see I did not use variables for the Scalar upper and lower bounds, which caused it to work. I tried what you suggested deleting the clones and making a mat mask and passing it into inRange however it only worked when I was not using variables to store the values then calling them in inRange. Why is this happening?

Comment: It's possible you are having a namespace collision. A lot of OpenCV stuff is common across libraries (`Size`, `Rect`, etc.). When declaring variables using OpenCV types, try to always use `cv::`. For instance: `cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255);`. It's hard to diagnose this problem without knowing more about your setup, but I suspect your issue is more an IDE, C++ error than an OpenCV.